# MySQL Cluster Auto-Installer user permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-cluster

i'm trying to install MySQL Cluster 7.5 with the auto-installer, but i'm having problems with the user account needed for the install. 
On step 1 you have to specify a linux user and password. If you provide the root user, then the cluster deploy and start fails with the follwing error:

[ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

Later, I read in the documentation that root shouldn't be used so i created a new user on all linux nodes, without any permissions, the installation fails again with "permission denied". So... i gave that user sudo permissions to run any command, but the installation still fails with "permission denied".

i cannot find any document with the requiered permissions to install mysql cluster using the auto installer so... help!

what permissions do i need to perform an installation?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to do the following:

1. Create 'mysql' user and 'mysql' group.
2. Make sure this user have read-write permissions on the base and data dir, which you configure them at step 2 'define hosts'.
3. Give it root permissions to 'mysql' user and put it inside 'mysql' group.

Note 1: Remember you must put the 'mysql' user credentials in the step 1 of the auto installer.

Note 2: You could use these commands to change permissions to directories mentioned above:
- chown -R root:mysql /base/and/data/directory/ OR 
- chown -R mysql:mysql /base/and/data/directory/
AND
- chmod -R g+w /base/directory
- chmod -R g+w /data/directory

Please, you tell me if it works for you...